# Compare subsequent rows in SQLite with JOINS

Tags: sql, sqlite, join

I have a table MyTable that has an ordered column A (no primary key)

```
A
____
2
3
4
10
13
14
20
```

I want to compare this table to itself so I have something like this

```
T1.A  T2.A
________
2     3
3     4
4     10
10    13
13    14
14    20
20    null
```

T1 and T2 are aliases for MyTable.

So how do I compare each row to next row without using stuff such as WITH AS but with an ordinary JOIN? This is because SQLite does not have the WITH-AS clause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this, use a correlated subquery:

```
select t1.a,
       (select t2.A from t t2 where t2.A > t1.A order by t2.A limit 1
       ) as NextA
from t t1
```

Comment: Thanks, I was always looking for JOINS and totally forgot about correlated queries. Thanks!